# Pretty, Tidy JSON output using Zend Framework?

Tags: json, zend-framework, helper, formatting

I am using the Zend Framework helper for JSON.
I am returning an array of data from a domain entity using a created method toArray().

Is there a way to change the format from tidy to pretty?

PHP

```
$data = array(
            "success"=>true,
            "user"=>array($user->toArray())
            );
$this->_helper->json($data);
```

Body Response:

```
{"success":true,"user":[{"id":9,"displayName":"joey","firstName":"joe","lastName":"blow","email":"joeblow@yahoo.com","role":"user"}]}
```

To:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "user": [{
     "id":9, 
     "displayName":"joey",
     "firstName":"joe",
     "lastName":"blow",
     "email":"joeblow@yahoo.com",
     "role":"user"
  }]
}
```

Comment: you can use a json formatter. there may even exists offline versions. ask google for more infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tested and would depend on some of your json implementation but you could try :

```
$json = Zend_Json::encode($data);
$json = Zend_Json::prettyPrint($json);

$this->_helper->json($json, true, array('encodeData' => false));
```

Comment: Looks like echo Zend_Json::prettyPrint($data) is my only option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$json = Zend_Json::encode($phpNative);
echo Zend_Json::prettyPrint($json, array("indent" => " "));
```

LINK : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.basics.html